# Maximum available threads in Windows system? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the code in C++ to get maximum number of avalible threads in system?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, Doing a web search, seems the limit is around 2000 threads per process, depending on stack size. Using a larger than default stack size would allow for more threads per process. `GetSysInfo` can be used to get the number of logical processors (cores and/or hyperthreads) .

Comment: This would be highly OS-dependent.  Just curious -- what are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by max threads?  Are you meaning max processor hardware  threads/cores?  or are you meaning how many threads can I create in the OS?  Usually the later is a resource limit which is rather high. and not something you'll want to worry about.

Comment: _"...By default, every thread has one megabyte of stack space. Therefore, you can create at most 2,048 threads. ..."_ source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread

Comment: I think the reason for the 2048 limit was the 32 bit address space gave you 2GB of user space for your program so theoretically 2048 was the maximum number of threads created each with a 1MB stack. Now that it's 2020 and 32 bit code and OSs are not the often used I am not sure that applies at all. I think Microsoft needs to update that.

Comment: As @Matt asked, I'd also like to know what "_maximum number of avalible threads in system_" means. When I made my answer I interpreted it as the number of available hardware threads and not an upper limit of the many thousands of threads Windows has running at any given point in time. Can you clarify this Billie? I'd like to remove my alswer if I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not have the concept of a maximum number of threads.

It does have the concept of a thread failing to be created, by raising `std::system_error`. This can happen for any number of reasons, including your OS deciding it doesn't want to spawn any more threads - either because you've hit a hard or soft limit on thread count, or because it actually cannot create a thread if it wanted (e.g. your address space is consumed).

The actual limit would need to be queried in an OS-specific way, outside the C++ standard. For example, on Linux one could query `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` and any relevant ulimit and compute a possible limit.

On Windows there is no queryable limit, and you are limited by address space. See for example ["Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773) exploring this limitation.

The reason systems don't make this trivial to query is because it should not matter. You will quickly exhaust your usable cores long before you hit any practical limit in thread count. Don't make so many threads!

Comment: There is IMHO another good [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads#thread-limits).

Comment: This returns me "Created threads 100000." In my assignment I have to separate process (program) to number of threads that are available in my system. We use omp.

Comment: @BillieStyles Sorry, I can't tell if you're asking a question. Sounds like indeed you are asking for a maximum thread count - as noted, this is OS-specific as well as program-specific, and many factors apply. (And, in practice it doesn't matter because too many threads is counter-productive.)

Comment: @BillieStyles If you have a CPU intense program that you want to parallelize, you rarely want to use more threads than what is supported in hardware but if the threads have low CPU usage, you may very well create a lot more of them. The Windows system limit of threads should however _never_ be an issue. If that really _is_ an issue, your program should be redesigned. If you create 100000 threads to run simultaneously, I'd say you're using the wrong limit or it's time to redesign.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency)

- Returns the number of hardware thread contexts. If this value is not computable or well-defined, an implementation should return 0.

You can however create many more `std::thread` objects, but only this many threads will execute in parallel at any time.

For OpenMP (OMP) you also have [`omp_get_max_threads()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-functions?view=vs-2019#omp-get-max-threads)

- Returns an integer that is equal to or greater than the number of threads that would be available if a parallel region without [num_threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-clauses?view=vs-2019#num-threads) were defined at that point in the code.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @GManNickG I think it depends on how the question is interpreted. If this isn't what OP meant, I'll remove it.

Comment: `GetSysInfo`  will return the number of "processors" (this includes hyperthreading).

Comment: @rcgldr You'll get the same answer from `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`

Comment: Note: The author of that documentation page maybe did not understand the meaning of the word, "[concurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))." A program might have _thousands_ of concurrent threads, but `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns the maximum number of them that can be _simultaneously executing code_ at the same instant in time. (I.e., the number of threads that can run _[in parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing)_.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Reworded it a bit.